# HighCharts data defined in a HTML Table using PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts, datatables

I'm using [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed) to display a chart that is pulling data on **HTML Table** and my table is populated by **PHP**. Somehow it displaying the Title of the Chart which is **Announcement Likes Chart** but the **Bar Chart** is not included in it. Any **answer** with or without explanation is highly appreciated :)

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="page-header">
                      <h1 id="tables">Announcement Table</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tablecon" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
                      <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-hover ">
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th></th>
                                  <th>Title</th>
                                  <th>Likes</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody class="table table-bordered table-hover ">
                              <?php
                            //set up mysql connection
                            mysql_connect("localhost", "brmhelpd_root", "siopao04") or die(mysql_error());
                            //select database
                            mysql_select_db("brmhelpd_brm") or die(mysql_error());
                                    //select all records form tblmember table
                                    $query = 'SELECT type,title,likes FROM newsfeed ORDER BY created_at ASC';
                                    //execute the query using mysql_query
                                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                                    if($result === FALSE) { 
                                        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
                                    }
                                   //then using while loop, it will display all the records inside the table
                                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo ' <tr> ';
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['type'];
                                        echo ' </td> ';
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['title'];
                                        echo ' </td> ';
                                        echo ' <td> ';
                                        echo $row['likes'];
                                        echo ' </td> ';
                                        echo ' </tr> ';
                                    }
                              ?>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
              </div>
          </div>
          </table>

      </div>
          </div>

      </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="login-folder/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="login-folder/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
             $('#datatable').DataTable( {
                 "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, -1], [5, 10, 25, "All"]]
             });
         } );
    </script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#tablecon').highcharts({
                data: {
                    table: 'datatable'
                },
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Announcement Likes Chart'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: true,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Units'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please avoid using the _deprecated_ mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: ok thanks for the info but i dont have much time to change my codes the deadline is very near sad

Comment: okayy. so did you try it with the dummy data first as given in the link you provided?

Comment: nope wait ill try it first

Comment: Ahh, do that first. atleast make sure it works then populate it dynamically.

Comment: Hah, just what I thought! Let me see if I can get that up and running `;-)`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/ works okay here

Comment: yah but i tried it still blank rofl

Comment: what is the output for your sql query? paste that

Comment: Why you cannot return a JSON in your php and then load that by $.ajax() ? Seems that is simpler and you avoid parsing of table.

Comment: @SebastianBochan ok thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm giving up to this problem. I'll populate my table with ajax better thanks for [Sebastian Bochan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan) suggestion.